# Like cats and dogs?

Tags: idiom

In American we say "They fought like cats and dogs." We also say "It's raining cats and dogs." Does German have something idiomatic for these two uses of cats and dogs? BTW, are these sayings proper Oxford English?

Comment: The last question is probably a suitable question for English, but off topic here.

Comment: I'm a bit undecided about what to make of this question. On the one hand, you are asking about a specific element that is common to several American figures of speech, namely "cats and dogs". Maybe you could have the question rather focus that aspect. If the question just is "What are German equivalents for these two figures of speech (that happen to be similar in American English)?" then I suggest you ask two questions that can be answered separately. I for one can instantly think of an idiomatic way to express the first one in German, but none for the second, hence I cannot post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

*It's raining cats and dogs.*

> Es schüttet wie aus Kübeln. *(simpler:* Es schüttet.*)*

*It's raining buckets. / It's bucketing down.*

---

*They fought like cats and dogs.*

> Sie sind wie Hund und Katze (zueinander).

*"They are like dog and cat (to each other)."*

Comment: "Sie sind wie Hund und Katze" - ist das wirklich eine Redewendung? Was soll denn das heißen? Selbst wenn man die nicht dem Stereotyp entsprechenden, aber durchaus gewöhnlich vorkommenden Fälle von Hunden und Katzen, die im selben Haushalt friedlich zusammenleben, außer Acht lässt, kann das ja alles von "sie vertragen sich nicht besonders gut und sind sich gegenseitig im Weg" bis hin zu "sie sind Todfeinde" bedeuten.

Comment: Ich kenne diese Redewendung für » Sie kämpfen ständig. «

Comment: "Sie sind wie Hund und Katz" ist doch total geläufig. Wundert mich, dass das wieder welche gar nicht kennen. Es heißt einfach, dass zweie total gegensätzlich sind und sich deswegen gar nicht vertragen.

Comment: Ich kenn das Sprichwort als "sie sind wie Katz und Maus" (ich bin aber auch mit Tom und Jerry groß geworden).

Comment: @Iris Bei Katze und Maus (wenn wir vom realen Leben ausgehen und nicht von Zeichentrickfilmen oder -serien) ist aber die Katze haushoch überlegen und die Maus nur ein Spielball/Opfer. Bei Katze und Hund - zumindest bis zu mittelgroßen Hunden - geht es um zwei halbwegs ebenbürtige Gegner, bei denen auch beide als Aggressor in einem Streit in Frage kommen.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf das mag sein, und trotzdem bedeutet es: [1] wie in einer permanenten Gegnerschaft, sich oft streitend (https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wie_Katz_und_Maus)

Answer (score 3):

The english idiom

> It's raining cats and dogs.

corresponds to something like one of these german idioms:

> - Es gießt in Strömen.
> - Es schüttet/ regnet wie aus Eimern/ Kübeln.

Unfortunately, I have no proper german idiom in mind that would correspond to

> They fought like cats and dogs.

But I would translate it as something like:

> - Sie stritten/ zankten wie die Hühner/ Hähne.
> - Sie verhielten sich wie [Streithammel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Streithammel).
> - Sie waren [wie Hund und Katz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wie_Hund_und_Katz).

---

Your second question, regarding whether the english sayings are proper Oxford English, cannot be answered here.

Comment: At least "raining cats and dogs" was mentioned in my English classes in school, and in German schools the base for teaching English is British English, not American English.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  It seems everybody who learned English in a German school was taught that cats and dogs raining thing. On the other hand, I was told by an English teacher in the UK recently that actually nobody there used that term any more. He said it was popular to some extent in the 19th century. And with Germans, for reasons beyond his understanding.

Answer (score 3):

In our region* we have the idiom

> Es regnet junge Hunde (It's raining young dogs)

for very strong rain. That would be the closest to

> "It's raining cats and dogs."

---

* Region NRW / Niederrhein